# How to handle undefined behaviour caused by user

Tags: c++, error-handling, exception

I have a look-up method that takes a vector of strings (tags), searches a vector of objects and returns a pointer to an object if the argument tags matches the tags of the object. If the user specifies a query that results in no match i just return a nullptr:

```
Entity* Scene::findEntity(std::vector<std::string> tags)
{
    int matchIndex = findMatchIndex(tags);
    if (tags.size()  == 0 || matchIndex == -1) {
        std::string msg = "No entity with tag(s): " + formatTags(tags) + " found.";
        printf(msg.c_str());
        return nullptr;
    }
    else {
        return &_entities.at(matchIndex);
    }
}
```

So say for example that the user tries this:

```
TestScene::TestScene()
{
    Entity player = Entity({ "player" }, { new Drawable(), new Transform(), new Collidable(), new PlayerScript() });

    spawnEntity(player);

    Entity* testPlayer = findEntity({ "Plsdfsdfdsfayer" });
    testPlayer -> getTags();
}
```

This will cause undefined behaviour since findEntity returns nullptr.

What would be a good way to handle when no object is found? Should i crash the program deliberatly to prevent undefined behaviour when the user tries to interact with the nullptr? It feels like overkill to exit just because an object is not found ...

Comment: It depends on your use case. If it's an "exceptional" case then you should throw an exception and the consumer should catch this, if not, returning `nullptr` is just fine. It's up to the consumer of the method to check for `nullptr` and read the documentation so it is known that your method can return `nullptr`.

Comment: Document the function and have the user read that documentation.  Purposefully not checking for return values is a mistake that no responsible programmer should make.

Comment: You have two variables that share a same name

Comment: You should follow the behavior of std find methods: return an `end()` iterator if nothing found. You should also pass `tags` by reference.

Comment: Another issue is that if those entities are stored in a vector, you're returning the address of one of the vector's values.  This is dangerous in that the address will become invalidated if the vector is resized, thus your user would be holding onto an address that is no longer valid.

Comment: @RickAstley Thanks!  I would prefer not to rely on the consumer catching exepctions since i'm trying to make the software as beginner-friendly as possible so i will probably stick with returning nullptr. Only one question though, what  defines an exepctional case?

Comment: @ojojkolol -- An example of an exceptional case is one where there it is guaranteed that the entity *must* exist, and if that guarantee fails, an exception is thrown.

Comment: If a library that uses your code dereferences a nullptr, it's not your library's problem. They get a pointer back, so it's them who needs to check it before dereferencing it.

Comment: For this kind of things, I usually provide 2 functions. A `find`, which returns a pointer. And a `get`, which returns a reference. `get` calls `find`, and if the element not found, it fatal errors/throws. The caller will know, which variant it needs.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, so should i use an array instead? Or maybe use some sort of id to index map container that i manage myself and instead of the pointer return the id?

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, i will probably just let the user know that if nothing is found a nullptr will be returned.

Comment: @ojojkolol -- You can use a `std::list` which does not invalidate existing entries on resize.  For `std::list`, only if that entry is removed will a pointer/iterator to the entry will become invalid.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Im considering using another data structure, although would you think it's possible to have a have a method that notifies when the vector gets reallocated? For example, whenever something is pushed back i check if a realocation occured, if true i would loop trough all the entity pointers and overwrite them with the new ones.

Comment: @ojojkolol -- Better use a different data structure.  A vector can be resized not only by using `push_back`.  You have `insert`, `resize()`, even things that call `push_back` behind the scenes such as usage of `std::back_inserter()`.